# FPV Racing Drone Reccomendation

Tags: drone, vr-headset

I'm looking for an FPV racing drone that has a sturdy frame and comes with everything I need (except VR goggles if it links with your phone).
I also don't have a soldering iron so I won't be able to solder. I usually buy off of amazon, and if it's sold on there, that'd be great. I want it to have blade guards as well that make it able to fly indoors. I'm an experienced pilot, so it doesn't have to be beginner friendly. I don't want to have to spend over $200 on this, too. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many drones on the market. What are you looking for? Do you want the drone to have a good battery or maybe durability?

I can recommend [EMAX Hawk Sport 5.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YF45T28) It comes with a great design and overall quality. It's under $200 too.

Don't forget to check these sites. Maybe you'll find something useful.

https://mydroneauthority.com/reviews/best-racing-drones-for-sale/

https://uavcoach.com/fpv-quadcopter-drone-systems/

https://www.aniwaa.com/buyers-guide/drones/best-fpv-racing-drones/  (2019 list)